# C# (Unit Testing): I need to make it impossible to write to a file through code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, writefile

Basically, here's the situation. I have the following:

```
public IService Service { get; set; } //Set to MyMockedService class.

public Boolean DoFoo()
{
    //possible other ways of returning true/false...

    Boolean success = true;

    //Get FileInfo[] items

    foreach (var item in items)
        DoOtherFoo(item);
}

public Boolean DoOtherFoo(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    String filepath = //manipulate fileInfo.FullName;

    Byte[] file = Service.GetFile(filepath)
    try
    {
        WriteBinaryFile(filepath, file); //How can I force file writing to throw an exception
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically, In testing DoFoo() I have a lot of paths that could return true/false. I've unit tested all of them except the final one... where it attempts to write the files and if even one of the files can't be written for some reason, it fails and sends back false. At first I figured if I tried to setup a bad filename such as "bad*file" it would throw an exception in the WriteFile but I didn't even get that far because I can't create a FileInfo object using illegal characters. So I'm looking for another way to make it so that it would be impossible to write the file so I can get back a false.

Comment: why don't you just open the file while running your app. depending on what file it is, that current app could be locking it down and therefore you won't be able to write to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good unit tests are isolated ones. It means they are absolutely idependent of any environment (files, database, network etc.). If your code uses files to store data in it, you should hide by some interface, the production and test code would use different implmementation. Production will really do Write to file, test one will only emulate it.

```
public interface IStorage
{
  bool StoreToFile(string path, string file, byte[] data);
}

public class Storage : IStorage
{
  public bool StoreToFile( ... )
  {
     return WriteToFile( ... );
  }
}

public class StorageMock : IStorage
{
   public bool StoreToFile (...)
   {
      return false;  //or true, depends on you test case
   }
}
```

Now in tests you are able to "subtitue" real implmementaion with fake one. This is called mocking.

Desing that takes into considiration called "Inversion of Control". There are also a bunch of frameworks that allows you to use "Investion of Control" throught dependency injection (StructureMap, Ninject, Wisdor)

Comment: Agreed, but something, somewhere eventually has to write the file. So I think it's worth pointing out that you're really just isolating the code that you can't unit test (but could likely write integration tests for).

Comment: yeap, you can finally do integration test and debug and see actual exception message, to see what is going wrong there

Comment: So, if this is the area where I decide to leave the actual writing call, I shouldn't need to unit test for it, but instead leave it up to integration testing?

Comment: @michael Leaving the writing logic in a method within this class would also mean not being able to fully unit test any method that uses it.

Answer (score 3):

Is `WriteBinaryFile` a method in this same `class`?

You could create an object with this sole responsibility, but start with an abstraction:

```
public interface IBinaryFileWriter
{
    void WriteBinaryFile(string filepath, Byte[] file);
}
```

Now you can inject this dependency into the class that you are testing, preferably as a constructor argument.

In your application, you'll use an implementation of `IBinaryFileWriter` that does exactly what your current method does.

In tests, though, you can supply a mock that you can configure to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test can use [System.IO.File.Open(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx) with `FileShare` set to `None`. Any other process will fail to open that file.

Comment: Yes, any other process *including* a legitimate instance of your unit test (perhaps a command line build whilst you're also building & running tests inside VS). This is why isolation is important. Repeatability of unit tests is paramount to their usefulness. If it fails *sometimes*, developers lose trust in them and it is far more difficult to rectify the underlying issue.

Comment: And, yes, this particular case could be addressed by using `Path.GetTempFileName()` or similar, but my point is really a wider one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the internals of WriteBinaryFile. You need to be testing WriteBinaryFile at a more granular level. I assume that that's your function...I don't recognize that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the decompiled code for ctor of FileInfo

```
public FileInfo(string fileName)
{
    if (fileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
    }
    base.OriginalPath = fileName;
    string fullPathInternal = Path.GetFullPathInternal(fileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { fullPathInternal }, false, false).Demand();
    this._name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    base.FullPath = fullPathInternal;
}
```

So after creating a FileInfo you can set the FullPath and OriginalPath to an invalid filepath by reflection and make the WriteBinary throwing exceptoin

Just like that:

```
 FileInfo info = new FileInfo("c:\\1.txt");
 info.GetType().BaseType.GetField(
      "FullPath", 
      BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance)
   .SetValue(info, "invalidpath");
 info.GetType().BaseType.GetField(
      "OriginalPath", 
       BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance)
   .SetValue(info, "invalidpath");
```